# Verify Casorati-Weierstrass on example

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I verify [Casorati-Weierstrass](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154703/casorati-weiestrass-theorem-for-essential-singularities/154707) theorem on the example ?$$f(z)=\sin\frac{1}{z}$$

Comment: I think you meant to link to a different page.

Comment: @DisplayName do you want check that every ball centerd in $0$ has image dense in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: that I did ^^ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154703/casorati-weiestrass-theorem-for-essential-singularities/154707#154707

Comment: @DisplayName or do you want prove that in $0$ f has a essential singularity? for then you apply Casorati-Weierstrass?

Comment: @EdgarMatias The problem is not worded that specific. That's why I can only guess. I think, I probably have to show that f meets the requirements for Casorati-Weierstrass(the essential singularity) and that its dense in 0. I dont think I can simply apply the theorem

Comment: My guess is that the exercise maker wants you to check explicitly that the image of $f$ over an arbitrarily small punctured disc $0 < |z| < r$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. The easiest way to do this is to solve the equation $f(z) = w$. (But it sounds like you have already done this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify the Laurent series expansion has infinitely negative terms. But this should not be difficult because you can compare the number $$\frac{e^{\frac{i}{z}}-e^{-\frac{i}{z}}}{2i}$$with arbitrally given $\frac{1}{z^{n}}$ near 0. Or maybe you can expand straightforwardly. I do not know what else you need to "verify" (big or small) Picard's theorem in this case.

To visualize go to

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+sin[1%2Fz]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20sin%5B1/z%5D)

Comment: Do you maybe mean like this: $$sin\frac{1}{z}=\sum_{n=-1}^{-infinity} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: This is almost certainly *not* the intension of the exercise.